# How to use a javascript variable in CFM page?

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016, coldfusion-2018

I have a code in coldfusion pop up, the parent page has the variable which I intend to use in my CFM page.

I am able to get the variable in jacascript through the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var selectedUserIdForPassword = $('#selectedUsers').val();
</script>
```

selectedUsers variable is in parent CFM page of the pop up, now I want to use this javascript variable in a query in the pop up's CFM page.

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1618-ask-ben-converting-javascript-variables-into-coldfusion-variables.htm

Comment: As well as the above, I think you could benefit from improving your understanding of how web-request processing works: https://blog.adamcameron.me/2012/10/the-coldfusion-requestresponse-process.html

Comment: You can send it as a url variable.